# Timers and Delay issues

Tags: jquery

I have a script function that allows an image to rotate between 4 images. The function has a 2 second timeout when the page loads, then waits 8 seconds before it rotates to the second (and subsequent images from there)

What I need to do is set it so that the image begins rotating soon after loading in, then has the 8 second interval for rotating after that.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spddyday/1/)

```js
    $(function(){
     $('.fadein2 > :gt(0)').hide();
     setTimeout(function() {
     setInterval(function(){$('.fadein2 :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein2');}, 8000);
     }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
    .fadein { 
     position:relative; 
     height:400px; 
     width:300px;
     float: left;
     padding: 5px; 
    }
    .fadein > * { 
     position:absolute; 
     left:0; 
     top:0; 
     display:block;
     padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="/ContractHome.html">
    <div class="fadein" style="padding: 15px;">
      <img src="http://www.view-restaurant.co.uk/uploads/1/1/9/4/11949146/2826626.jpg?902" alt="">
      <img src="http://d.otcdn.com/imglib/hotelfotos/8/203/hotel-hamilton-island-reef-view-whitsunday-islands-hamilton-island-018.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://www.view-restaurant.co.uk/uploads/1/1/9/4/11949146/2826626.jpg?902" alt="">
      <img src="http://d.otcdn.com/imglib/hotelfotos/8/203/hotel-hamilton-island-reef-view-whitsunday-islands-hamilton-island-018.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <p class="hoverText" style="top: 100px;width: 100%;">Contract</p>
</div>
```

Comment: so where's the problem?

Comment: Yeahhh... I'm also struggling to see the issue here. You need to define what you mean by 'soon'.

Comment: The fiddle does nothing.

Comment: doesn't have jquery uri. add it and see whats happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved your problem.
You need to call your function twice, one on `setTimeout` and second on `setInterval`.

**`setInterval`** is your long time (what you call after)

and **`setTimeout`** for your start time (what you call soon).

Update your code on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/spddyday/5/)

**and here:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.fadein > :gt(0)').hide();
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
     fadeInFadeOut()
    }, 8000);
    fadeInFadeOut()
  }, 2000);
});

function fadeInFadeOut(){
 $('.fadein :first-child')
    .fadeOut()
    .next()
    .fadeIn()
    .end()
    .appendTo('.fadein')
}
```

```css
.fadein {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fadein > * {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="/ContractHome.html">
    <div class="fadein" style="padding: 15px;">
      <img src="http://www.view-restaurant.co.uk/uploads/1/1/9/4/11949146/2826626.jpg?902" alt="">
      <img src="http://d.otcdn.com/imglib/hotelfotos/8/203/hotel-hamilton-island-reef-view-whitsunday-islands-hamilton-island-018.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://www.view-restaurant.co.uk/uploads/1/1/9/4/11949146/2826626.jpg?902" alt="">
      <img src="http://d.otcdn.com/imglib/hotelfotos/8/203/hotel-hamilton-island-reef-view-whitsunday-islands-hamilton-island-018.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <p class="hoverText" style="top: 100px;width: 100%;">Contract</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works exactly as I needed. Sorry if my initial post was a bit confusing. I was trying to describe it in my head and the words hit the post in that order. But this works perfectly.